# Почему написанная мной обертка для COM, работает быстрее чем то что предлагает .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, com

Предыстория была такова, что заметил небольшой интересный факт:

> При вызове `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)`, освобождается только
>   `RCW`, а у интерфейсов всегда оставались ссылки и они не
>   освобождались.

Столкнулся с проблемой очень долгого создания объектов `COM`, используя именно стандартные средства `.NET`, а если быть точнее, то это интерфейсы помеченные аттрибутами

```
[ComImport, Guid(...), IntyerfaceType(...)]
interface ISomeIUnknownInterface
{
...
}
```

Написанная мной обертка, работает непосредственно с указателем на интерфейс, имеет `IUnknown` интерфейс, и работает через виртуальную таблицу этого объекта.

Сделал тест скорости создания как минимум главного объекта `IDXGIFactory`, и при работе со стандартными интерфейсами, объект был получен спустя 2 секунды после вызова, когда возврат указателя на объект занимает порядка 10~100 мс.

Интерфейс и класс выглядят вот так:

```
[Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface IUnknown : IDisposable
{
    int QueryInterface(in Guid riid, out IntPtr unknownObjectPtr);
    uint AddRef();
    uint Release();
}
```

```
public class Unknown : IUnknown
{
    public const uint LastMethodId = 2u;

    protected readonly int MethodsCount = typeof(IUnknown).GetMethods().Length;

    public Unknown(IntPtr objectPtr)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Zero == objectPtr)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("IUnknown object pointer cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.",
                nameof(objectPtr));
        }

        Pointer = objectPtr;
        AddMethodsToVTableList(0, MethodsCount);
    }

    protected IntPtr Pointer { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsValid => Pointer != IntPtr.Zero;

    protected List<IntPtr> VirtualTableAddresses { get; private set; } = new List<IntPtr>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public int QueryInterface(in Guid riid, out IntPtr unknownObjectPtr)
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<QueryInterfaceDelegate>().Invoke(this, in riid, out unknownObjectPtr);
    }

    public uint AddRef()
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<AddRefDelegate>().Invoke(this);
    }

    public uint Release()
    {
#if DEBUG
        uint result =
#else
        return
#endif
            GetMethodDelegate<ReleaseDelegate>().Invoke(this);

#if DEBUG
        Trace.WriteLine($"{typeof(Unknown).Namespace} — {this}.Release() return value: {result}", "DEBUG");
#endif

        return result;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposed)
    {
        if (IsDisposed || !IsValid)
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            return;
        }

        Release();

        if (isDisposed)
        {
            Pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            VirtualTableAddresses.Clear();
            VirtualTableAddresses = null;
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    ~Unknown()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void AddMethodsToVTableList(int startMethodId, int methodsCount)
    {
        IntPtr virtualTablePtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(this);

        for (int i = startMethodId; i < methodsCount + startMethodId; i++)
        {
            VirtualTableAddresses.Add(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(virtualTablePtr, i * IntPtr.Size));
        }
    }

    protected T GetMethodDelegate<T>() where T : Delegate
    {
        ComMethodIdAttribute attribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<ComMethodIdAttribute>();
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<T>(VirtualTableAddresses[(int) attribute.Id]);
    }

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(Unknown obj)
    {
        return obj.Pointer;
    }

    [ComMethodId(0u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int QueryInterfaceDelegate(IntPtr selfPtr, in Guid riid, out IntPtr unknownObjectPtr);

    [ComMethodId(1u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate uint AddRefDelegate(IntPtr selfPtr);

    [ComMethodId(2u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate uint ReleaseDelegate(IntPtr selfPtr);
}
```

Один из наследованных интерфейсов и объектов:

```
[Guid("aec22fb8-76f3-4639-9be0-28eb43a67a2e")]
public interface IObject : IUnknown
{
    int SetPrivateData(in Guid name, uint dataSize, byte[] data);
    int SetPrivateDataInterface(in Guid name, IUnknown unknown = null);
    int GetPrivateData(in Guid name, ref uint dataSize, [In, Out] byte[] data = null);
    int GetParent(in Guid riid, out IntPtr parent);
}
```

```
public class Object : Unknown, IObject
{
    protected new const uint LastMethodId = Unknown.LastMethodId + 4u;
    protected new readonly int MethodsCount = typeof(IObject).GetMethods().Length;

    public Object(IntPtr objectPtr) : base(objectPtr)
    {
        AddMethodsToVTableList(base.MethodsCount, MethodsCount);
        MethodsCount = base.MethodsCount + MethodsCount;
    }

    public int SetPrivateData(in Guid name, uint dataSize, byte[] data)
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<SetPrivateDataDelegate>().Invoke(this, in name, dataSize, data);
    }

    public int SetPrivateDataInterface(in Guid name, IUnknown iUnknown = null)
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<SetPrivateDataInterfaceDelegate>()
            .Invoke(this, in name, (Unknown) iUnknown ?? IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public int GetPrivateData(in Guid name, ref uint dataSize, [In, Out] byte[] data = null)
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<GetPrivateDataDelegate>().Invoke(this, in name, ref dataSize, data);
    }

    public int GetParent(in Guid riid, out IntPtr parent)
    {
        return GetMethodDelegate<GetParentDelegate>().Invoke(this, in riid, out parent);
    }

    [ComMethodId(Unknown.LastMethodId + 1u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int SetPrivateDataDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr, in Guid name, uint dataSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] data);

    [ComMethodId(Unknown.LastMethodId + 2u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int SetPrivateDataInterfaceDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr, in Guid name, IntPtr iUnknown);

    [ComMethodId(Unknown.LastMethodId + 3u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int GetPrivateDataDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr, in Guid name, ref uint dataSize, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] data = null);

    [ComMethodId(Unknown.LastMethodId + 4u), UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int GetParentDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr, in Guid riid, out IntPtr parent);
}
```

Такой интерйес и базовый класс, позволяют очень быстро описывать новые объекты, без необходимости дублирования наследуемых методов.

Почему такая реализация быстрее чем стандартные средства работы с `COM` в `.NET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему написанная мной обертка для COM, работает быстрее чем то что предлагает .NET?
> ...
> IDXGIFactory

Дело в том, что DirectX Использует особый облегченный вариант COM: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/thomasolsen/introducing-the-microsoft-direct2d-api

> Lightweight COM – Should use C++ style interfaces which model Direct3D usage. No support for proxies, cross-process remoting, BSTRs, VARIANTs, COM registration (e.g. the heavyweight stuff).

В DirectX используется API, основанный на IUnknown, и счетчики ссылок, но другие возможности COM, вроде регистрации COM-объектов в реестре, разных моделей многопоточности и т.п., не используются. Если обычный COM-объект создается через CoCreateInstance, то IDXGIFactory создается через отдельную функцию [CreateDXGIFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-createdxgifactory), которая не инициализирует возможности COM.

Но COM Interop в .NET рассчитан на полноценный COM, поэтому он довольно тяжелый. Этот код работает быстрее, потому что он с нуля реализует поддержку облегченного COM.