# HDR OpenGL эффект

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, шейдеры, glsl

Хочу реализовать HDR эффект подобно такому из игры SpaceEngine, однако все мои попытки дают какой-то не очень красивый результат, яркость картинки просто жёстко увеличивается и всё...
Вот три скрина из SpaceEngine и пара моих..
SpaceEngine:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот какой у меня результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Шейдеры hdr простые, взял их с learnopengl.

hdr.vs:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main() {
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

hdr.fs:

```
#version 460 core
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D hdrBuffer;
uniform bool hdr;
uniform float exposure;

void main() {
    const float gamma = 2.2;
    vec3 hdrColor = texture(hdrBuffer, TexCoords).rgb;
    if(hdr) {
        // reinhard
        // vec3 result = hdrColor / (hdrColor + vec3(1.0));
        // exposure
        vec3 result = vec3(1.0) - exp(-hdrColor * exposure);
        // also gamma correct while we're at it
        result = pow(result, vec3(1.0 / gamma));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        vec3 result = pow(hdrColor, vec3(1.0 / gamma));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
    }
}
```

В программе вызывается всё подобным образом:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
... // Рендер сцены
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
hdrShader.Use();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
hdrShader.SetBool("hdr", true);
hdrShader.SetFloat("exposure", 2.5f);
    
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
renderQuad();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Что я делаю не так?( Полагаю, нужен eye adaptation алгоритм, но так и не смог найти его...

Comment: Это скорее похоже на bloom.

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Bloom

Comment: @Никита Самоуков , думаете, всё дело в блуме?

Comment: Возьми капчуру рендера, да посмотри в чём там дело.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ты имеешь ввиду bloom эффект? Если да, то это немного другой эффект (не hdr) и для него пишется отдельный шейдер для постобработки. Если нет, то что именно тебе не нравится в твоём варианте, относительно SpaceEngine?

Comment: вопрос протух уже , год выпуска 2019

Comment: @MaksimLensky https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002270/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-com-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82, этот тоже? На который почти спустя 2 года дали ответ.?

Comment: @MaximLensky, Почему спустя 2 года-то?! 2 месяца назад вопрос задан мой, и ещё имеет актуальность...Просто я давно уже нашёл ответ, что это bloom эффект, совмещённый с hdr'ом и правильно настроенным алгоритмом eye adaption, чтоб яркость постепенно угасала